# Per Gem Out of memory for Singleton pattern

Tags: java, performance, out-of-memory

Just want to know if I have singleton object which has non static map. Why objects in maps are going to pergem space and not in heap. I can see from Visual VM that with intersession of object in Map pergem space is increasing.

What I was aware was only static variable and classes goes in pergem space rest all the objects should go to heap.

Is this because of singleton pattern where singleton object is static hence the reference is pointing to heap but still have retain size in pergem?

If this is the case what's the remedy to this problem.

Comment: Any field within a singleton is effectively static. Singletons just obfuscate. The PermGen (on implementations where it exists) will be full of objects allocated in it - class data and interned strings. If you're reloading class loaders it's possible that your statics are preventing old code from being unloaded. Most GC activity will ignore PermGen, so you may well see objects in there hanging around for longer than expected.

Comment: I'd say using singletons is the root problem. What about switching to DI and using [@Singleton](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Singleton.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem is: yes. Specifically, anytime[1] that you reference an object, directly or indirectly, from a static variable, then that object cannot be garbage collected and will eventually make its way to permgen.

The solution is to not use a singleton. However, this won't really solve your problem, since based on your question, the real issue that you have is that the hashmap keeps on growing. If you are using this as some form of cache, then you also need to set some kind of expiration on the cache, either by time or size, otherwise it will just continue to grow until you get an OOM.

[1] More or less true, this might not be true in the presence of certain classloader tricks.